# I have been trying to figure out what I am doing wrong in this linked list program

Tags: c++, data-structures

So I am trying to figure out on my own where my linked list program is going wrong.
The head is somehow getting updated. I know its a tiny mistake but I just not finding where I am going wrong. is it related to global declaration of the variable ?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct node {
    int data;
    struct node* next;
}* head = NULL;

void insert()
{
    struct node *newnode, *temp;
    temp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    newnode = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    cout << "Enter the element in the Linked list" << endl;
    cin >> newnode->data;
    newnode->next = NULL;
    if (head == NULL) {
        head = newnode;
        temp = head;
    }
    else {
        temp->next = newnode;
        temp = newnode;
    }
}
void display(struct node* p)
{
    while (p != NULL) {
        cout << " " << p->data << endl;
        p = p->next;
    }
}
int main()
{
    int ch;
    do {
        cout << "1.To Enter element in the Linked List" << endl;
        cout << "2.To DIsplay Element in the Linked List" << endl;
        cout << "3.To exit" << endl;
        cin >> ch;
        switch (ch) {
        case 1: {
            insert();
            break;
        }
        case 2: {
            display(head);
            break;
        }
        }
    } while (ch != 3);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: a) this is not C ! dont tag unrelated languages please b) What is wrong with the code?

Comment: Your insert can not work on the second or subsequent inserts. You need to actually traverse the list from head to add a new tail node or keep a pointer to the previous tail. You also allocate 2 nodes for every insert.

Comment: `temp = head;` in insert is pointless and leaks memory. It is pointless because when insert is done `temp` no longer exists. It leaks memory because `temp` pointed to an allocated node that is no longer accessible after the ``temp = head;` statement. However you do leak memory regardless.

Comment: My advice when it comes to pointers is to work it out with pen and paper before writing code.

Comment: You shouldn't use malloc and free. Use new and delete or use smart pointers/STL containers. This code is C with iostream. You should either replace iostream by stdio.h and make it a real C program or you should rewrite the program to modern C++.

Comment: Read [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Enable all warnings and debug info (so with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compile with `g++ -Wall -g` )

Comment: About [using namespace std](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)...

Comment: You should prefer C++ *keywords* (`nullptr`) over old (obsolete?) C *macros* (`NULL`). Apart from, you can (but don't have to) check for null pointers more conveniently: `while(p)`, `if(!head)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues here, but the biggest one is you aren't appending to the end of your linked list. You need to find where the `->next` node is `NULL` for an item in your list, indicating the final item. Then your new node should become `->next` for that item. Also, be careful to check for `head` being `NULL`, in which case your new node should become `head`. You can modify the `insert()` function to work appropriately as so.

```
void insert()
{
    struct node *newnode, *temp;
    newnode = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    cout << "Enter the element in the Linked list" << endl;
    cin >> newnode->data;
    newnode->next = NULL;
    if (head == NULL) {
        head = newnode;
    } else {
        temp = head;
        while (temp->next != NULL) {
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        temp->next = newnode;
    }
}
```

Note: You are mixing elements of C and C++ (`malloc` is a C concept for dynamic memory allocation while `new` is a C++ concept), and as someone pointed out in the comments you should likely stick to one (unless you're taking a programming course and your professor wanted you to use certain methods).